# Javascript calender in Gridview not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

Calender in Gridivew not working . I am assigning unique values to gridview textbox and calender image button .But click event of calender not working in gridview.If tried same code without grid it is working fine.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BirthDate" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthDate" Text='<%# Eval("BirthDate", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")%>'
            runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
        <img id='<%# Eval("EmployeeId") %>' alt="" src="../../_layouts/Images/itevent.png" />
        <input type="text" id='<%# Eval("CtrlId") %>' style="display: none" name="txtExpDate"
            value="<%# Eval("BirthDate") %>" readonly="readonly">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Calendar.setup
                ({
                    inputField: '<%# Eval("CtrlId") %>',
                    ifFormat: '%d-%b-%Y ',
                    button: '<%# Eval("EmployeeId") %>',
                    align: 'Br'
                });                                                   
        </script>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery

```
       $(function () {
        $("[id$=txtBirthDate]").datepicker({
             showOn: 'focus'
             buttonImage:"images/calendar.gif" 

        });
    });
```

your aspx :

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "BirthDate">
     <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthDate" runat="server" ReadOnly = "true"></asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```